# What is a flag in Python while loops?

Tags: python

I came across "flag" in Python while loops; can anyone explain what that is?

Comment: There's no technical definition. A flag is just a variable whose value (usually Boolean) indicates a particular situation.

Comment: This needs more context, including example code. Otherwise it is unanswerable and will probably be closed.

Comment: Let's say you're looking for a needle in a haystack. You'd start with `needle_found = False`. That is a flag. `while not needle_found` is the criteria to keep going through the `while` loop. Once you find the needle, you set `needle_found = True` and the `while` loop stops

Answer (score 6):

A flag in Python acts as a signal to the program to determine whether or not the program as a whole or a specific section of the program should run.

In other words, you can set the flag to *True* and the program will run continuously until any type of event makes it *False*. Then the program, loop, or whatever you're using a flag for will stop.

For example:

```
prompt = "Tell me something cool: "
prompt += "\nEnter 'quit' to end the program"

active = True
while active:
    message = input(prompt)

    if message == 'quit'
        active = False
    else: 
        print(message)
```

In this example you can see that if a user types *'quit'*, it will end the program because it sets your flag to *False* thus stopping and exiting the while loop.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -4):

If you point to the below snippet [from Tutorials Point](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_while_loop.htm) then the 'flag' is a variable. Variables can have any values assigned to them. In this case it has a value of `1`.

While executes the code after (until end of the line) the colon as long as the condition in parentheses is `True`. In this case the code will be executed forever.

> ```
> #!/usr/bin/python
>
> flag = 1
> while (flag): print 'Given flag is really true!'
> print "Good bye!"`enter code here`
> ```

Comment: Dear @roganjosh , please read carefully !  this is NOT my example - this is an example from tutorialspoint that I suspect is the source of the question

Comment: @dexter103 he is right, though. You shouldn't post a subpar answer and defend it by saying, that it came from somewhere else