# Counting Consecutive Words Within a String

Tags: python, python-3.x

i am given string and supposed to count three consecutive words

so "Hello hello hello" is True,
"Hello hello 123 hello" is False,
and "Hello 123 hello hello hello" is True

i cannot find way to reset my counter when number showing up. in second example i return true because of this
i using is alpha by the way and am using python. can anyone help with counting the words the right way

```
counter = 0
    for word in words:
        if word.isalpha():
            counter += 1
```

Comment: What *specifically* are you having trouble with? You haven't even attempted to figure out if words are duplicates of the one before...

Answer (score -3, accepted):

also you can try this solution out...

```
succ = 0
for word in words.split():
    succ = (succ + 1)*word.isalpha()
    if succ == 3: return True
else: return False
```

Comment: This... doesn't work. All it does is count if there are 3 words (*any* words) in a row. And using `return` is a bad idea.

Comment: listen, this was voted as the answer so im obviously on to something here. go and please read the question again and see if it says anywhere that it has to count SPECIFIC words.

Comment: also feel free to write out an answer if you dont see the right solutions being given

Answer (score 2):

You may use `re.search` here:

```py
inp = ["Hello hello hello", "Hello hello 123 hello", "Hello 123 hello hello hello"]
for x in inp:
    if re.search(r'\b(\w+) \1 \1\b', x, flags=re.I):
        print("MATCH: " + x)
    else:
        print("NO MATCH: " + x)
```

This prints:

```
MATCH: Hello hello hello
NO MATCH: Hello hello 123 hello
MATCH: Hello 123 hello hello hello
```

Answer (score -2):

### you can try using *TWO* solutions:

1. use a flag

   - this would entail using a boolean before your loop and switching the bool value should you encounter a negation, or a number in this case
2. reset your counter using `isnum()`

   - this would be the easiest and simpler solution for you as you would only need to add an if statement to your code, reverting your counter should a number be found

for more information follow this link [What is a flag in python while loops?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59120347/what-is-a-flag-in-python-while-loops)
or this one https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_isnumeric.htm

Comment: `isnum()` won't work if the string given is all alphabetical. The question doesn't say anything about digits being used as separators.

Comment: `isnum()` can absolutely work
```
counter = 0
for word in words:
    if word.isalpha():
        counter += 1
    if word.isnum():
        counter = 0
```

Comment: It won't if the input is something like `"This is an input input input string"`, where there are no digits.

Comment: well then thats why its within an if clause which would be necessary as a digit would revert the counter

Comment: im not too sure you understood the question of the original post in its entirety